# UWP: Binding works on navigated to only, no updates in real time

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

The binding works well, but updates are not triggered on changes of the property.

So, my app has a complex data model, which I have to access from different pages. I therefore keep a static class through my App.xaml.cs – which is working fine. I’m trying to use this data model to update the background color of one frame, through a ColorPicker in another one. While the binding is no issue during when navigated to a frame, I can’t get it to work in real time, when both frames are visible next to each other.
Let me walk you through the code…

```
<Grid Background="{x:Bind local:App.myData.BgColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToSolidColorBrushConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SettingsColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ContentColumn" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.Column="0" x:Name="SettingsFrame"></Frame>
    <Frame Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ContentFrame"></Frame>

</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml** – here both frames are being defined, and the background color of question. I even created a converter, which I don’t seem to need actually. I can tell, that the converter is only used at launch time of the frame. The corresponding cs file contains the navigate calls only.

```
<Grid>
    <ColorPicker x:Name="BGColorPicker" 
                 Color="{x:Bind local:App.myData.BgColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

**SettingsPage.xaml** – This is the ColorPicker with the binding. I can see that this updates the data model as expected.

The problem appears to be, that even though my property changes, the binding is not updating the background color at runtime, only on startup. Why is that? And how can I change it to real time updates? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: I also faced the same problem , and finding no other solution , I used the `ColorChanged` event instead of Binding

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for your actual property?  It sounds like you haven't implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface OR made it a Dependency Property.

Comment: You really want to look at the Data Binding in depth article too if you don't know about INotifyPropertyChanged or Dependency Properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Data Binding in Depth" article was the missing link. As all of you suggested, I needed to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Thanks for your pointers. Then I had the problem, that somehow the whole thing created an infinite loop and I had to change the binding of the color picker to `OneTime` and do the updates through the `ColorChanged` event instead. Now it works. Thanks a lot everyone!